# Are variables, which linear combination results in a endogenous variable, endogenous?

Tags: regression, correlation, least-squares, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I'm a little bit confused....

Lets say I assume $x$ to be endogenous and I observe that

$x = a v_1 + b v_2 + c v_3$

so that $x$ can be expressed as the perfect linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3$. By this I mean that if I regress $x$ onto $v_1,v_2,v_3$ the $R^2$ will be 1 i.e. the model is deterministic.

In this particular case is it now wrong to assume that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are all exogenous? I mean how can a perfect fit of exogenous variables be endogenous. One of the $v$'s has to be endogenous to begin with? In terms of Regression-Analysis I would guess this is not true since we do this kind of thing all the time. The only difference is that we won't get a perfect fit hence my confusion.

If this would not be a problem I could always use one of the $v$'s as an instrument for $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It cannot be that $X_i$ is endogenous in a model and its perfect determinants are *all* exogenous. To see this recall that endogeneity of a regressor $X_i$ in the simple regression model
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i
$$
means that $\mathbb{E}(X_i\varepsilon_i) \neq 0$. Assume that the deterministic relationship between $X_i$ and $V_{1i}, V_{2i}, V_{3i}$ is $X_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 \gamma_j V_{ji}$.

This in turn implies that $\mathbb{E}(X_i\varepsilon_i) = \sum_{j=1}^3\gamma_j \mathbb{E}(V_{ji}\varepsilon_i)\neq 0$. In this scenario, it is possible that one, or at most two of the $V_{ji}$ variables are exogenous, but not that all the variables are exogenous.